# Speed Up Pandas Iterations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have DataFrame which consist of 3 columns: CustomerId, Amount and Status(success or failed).
The DataFrame is not sorted in any way. A CustomerId can repeat multiple times in DataFrame.

I want to introduce new columns into this DataFrame with below logic:

df[totalamount]= sum of amount for each customer where status was success.

I already have a running code but with df.iterrows which takes too much time. Thus requesting you to kindly provide alternate methods like pandas vectorization or numpy vectorization.

For Example, I want to create the 'totalamount' column from the first three columns:

```
   CustomerID  Amount   Status  totalamount
0           1       5  Success          105 # since both transatctions were successful
1           2      10   Failed           80 # since one transaction was successful
2           3      50  Success           50
3           1     100  Success          105
4           2      80  Success           80
5           4      60   Failed            0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `where` to mask the 'Failed' rows with `NaN` while preserving the length of the DataFrame. Then `groupby` the CustomerID and `transform` the sum of 'Amount' column to bring the result back to every row.

```
df['totalamount'] = (df.where(df['Status'].eq('Success'))
                       .groupby(df['CustomerID'])['Amount']
                       .transform('sum'))

   CustomerID  Amount   Status  totalamount
0           1       5  Success        105.0
1           2      10    Faled         80.0
2           3      50  Success         50.0
3           1     100  Success        105.0
4           2      80  Success         80.0
5           4      60   Failed          0.0
```

---

The reason for using `where` (as opposed to subsetting the DataFrame) is because groupby + sum defaults to sum an entirely `NaN` group to 0, so we don't need anything extra to deal with CustomerID 4, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
df_new = df.groupby(['CustomerID', 'Status'], sort=False)['Amount'].sum().reset_index()
df_new = (df_new[df_new['Status'] == 'Success']
            .drop(columns='Status')
            .rename(columns={'Amount': 'totalamount'}))
df = pd.merge(df, df_new , on=['CustomerID'], how='left')
```

I'm not sure at all but I think this may work